# Number of path from $A$ to $B$ in a grid that can be traveled either rightward or upward

Tags: combinatorics

> In the Road map shown in the Diagram, each line segment represents a street which can only be traveled along either the rightwards or upwards direction.
>
> Then what is the number of path from $A$ to $B$?

[image]

**I have a solution** which is given below in an answer, but I did not understand it, so please anyone like to explain me, Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried, and what are you having trouble with?

Comment: Number of possibilities from $A$ to $B$ : 6 left turns followed by 3 right turns........

Comment: actually I have a solution which is Given below but i did not understand it, so please anyone like to explain me, Thanks

Comment: Is you question that you want to see a fully worked solution, or that you want someone to explain the proof you've given in your answer? These are two different questions. If it's the latter, please delete your answer, and incorporate it in to your question with an edit.

Comment: Sorry Daniel Rust I should have post solution below the question. next time i will follow your instruction,Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solution Given as::

[image]

No. of path from $A$ to $B$ is

$(A\rightarrow B) = (A \rightarrow P \rightarrow B)+(A \rightarrow Q \rightarrow B)+(A \rightarrow R \rightarrow B)+(A \rightarrow S \rightarrow B)$

$\displaystyle  = \left(\binom{5}{1} \times 1\right)+\left(\binom{5}{2}\times \binom{5}
{4}\right)+\left(\binom{6}{5}\times \binom{4}{1}\right)+\left(1 \times 1\right)$

But I did not understand Solution, My Question is why we take points $P,Q,R$ and $S$

and How can i count no. of ways from $A$ to $B$ Through $P,Q,R$ and $S$

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Look at the point next to A (and call it C) and the point above A (and call it D). There is one possibility to each of the points. Then look at the point right above C. There are two possibilities to get there (by adding the number of possibilities to get to C and D). You can continue this inductively by adding the number of possibilities left of the point and under the point you are looking at.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let the number of paths from $A$ to $B$ be $M$ and the number of paths from $C$ to $D$ be $N$.
If we subtract $N$ from $M$ we can find the number of paths wanted in the original question.
We can find M and N by repetitive permutation.
$$M=\frac{(6+3)!}{6!3!}=84$$
$$N=\frac{(3+1)!}{3!1!}=4$$
$$M-N=80$$